# beautifulsoup extract data by searched class

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

Below code extracts Arbeitsatmosphare and Stadt data from reviews from below website. But extraction is based on index method, so if we would like to extract not Arteitsatmosphare, but Image (`rating_tags[12]`), we will have error, because sometimes we have only 2 or 3 items in review.

I would like to update this code to get below output. If we dont have Image use 0 or n/a.

```
         Arbeitsatmosphare | Stadt     | Image | 
   1.      4.00            | Berlin    | 4.00  |
   2.      5.00            | Frankfurt | 3.00  |
   3.      3.00            | Munich    | 3.00  |
   4.      5.00            | Berlin    | 2.00  |
   5.      4.00            | Berlin    | 5.00  |
```

My code is below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as  pd

arbeit = []
stadt = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Processing page {page}..")
        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagenconsulting/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        articles = soup.find_all('article')
        print("Number of articles: " + str(len(articles)))
        for article in articles:

            rating_tags = article.find_all('span', {'class' : 'rating-badge'})

            arbeit.append(rating_tags[0].text.strip())


            detail_div = article.find_all('div', {'class' : 'review-details'})[0]
            nodes = detail_div.find_all('li')
            stadt_node = nodes[1]
            stadt_node_div = stadt_node.find_all('div')
            stadt_name = stadt_node_div[1].text.strip()
            stadt.append(stadt_name)

        page += 1

        pagination = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'paginationControl'})
        if not pagination:
            break

df = pd.DataFrame({'Arbeitsatmosphäre' : arbeit, 'Stadt' : stadt})
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try/except`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as  pd
import re

arbeit = []
stadt = []
image = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Processing page {page}..")
        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagenconsulting/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        articles = soup.find_all('article')
        print("Number of articles: " + str(len(articles)))
        for article in articles:

            rating_tags = article.find_all('span', {'class' : 'rating-badge'})

            arbeit.append(rating_tags[0].text.strip())

            try:
                imageText = article.find('span', text=re.compile(r'Image')).find_next('span').text.strip()
                image.append(imageText)
            except:
                image.append('N/A')



            detail_div = article.find_all('div', {'class' : 'review-details'})[0]
            nodes = detail_div.find_all('li')
            stadt_node = nodes[1]
            stadt_node_div = stadt_node.find_all('div')
            stadt_name = stadt_node_div[1].text.strip()
            stadt.append(stadt_name)

        page += 1

        pagination = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'paginationControl'})
        if not pagination:
            break

df = pd.DataFrame({'Arbeitsatmosphäre' : arbeit, 'Stadt' : stadt, 'Image': image})
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Processing page 1..
Number of articles: 10
Processing page 2..
Number of articles: 10
Processing page 3..
Number of articles: 10
Processing page 4..
Number of articles: 4
   Arbeitsatmosphäre      Stadt Image
0               5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
1               5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
2               5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
3               5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
4               2,00  Wolfsburg  2,00
5               5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
6               5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
7               5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
8               5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
9               5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
10              5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
11              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
12              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
13              4,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
14              4,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
15              4,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
16              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
17              3,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
18              5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
19              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
20              5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
21              4,00  Wolfsburg  2,00
22              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
23              4,00  Wolfsburg   N/A
24              4,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
25              4,00  Wolfsburg  4,50
26              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
27              2,33  Wolfsburg  2,00
28              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
29              2,00  Wolfsburg  1,00
30              4,00  Wolfsburg  3,00
31              5,00  Wolfsburg  5,00
32              5,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
33              4,00  Wolfsburg  4,00
```

Comment: thanks. but this solution works, only it we have Image as 13th item. Sometimes we have Image, BUT some items are missing (for example in 5th comment), so in Image output we have n/a, but should have 2.0

Comment: ahhh ok. I was under the impression it's always in index postion 12. I'll adjust the code